# What is an "Echelon Basis"?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently working through Linear Algebra homework, and have run into this terminology.

```
Let W = span{p1,p2... p7} in P5
Find an echelon basis of W.
```

I am not including the defined polynomials for P, but am instead looking for more of an explanation of what an Echelon Basis is. In relation, I am aware of what a basis is, as well as how to find a basis of a given W.

Comment: Unusual language. I suspect they mean the nonzero rows of an echelon form of your original matrix. (So, in this context, you have to turn polynomials into the rows of your matrix in an obvious way.)

Comment: It means to find a basis $q=\{q_1,q_2,...,q_n\}$ of $W$ such that the matrix of the coordinates of $p_1,p_2,...,p_7$ in $q$ is a matrix in echelon form.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. Thank you!